# python3 typing: extract argument list from Callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Consider a function which wraps another function and puts the output into a singleton list:

```
def listify(func):
    return lambda *kargs, **kwargs: [func(*kargs, **kwargs)]
```

How would you type-hint this function in python3? This is my best attempt:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

def listify(func: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[..., List[T]]:
    return lambda *kargs, **kwargs: [func(*kargs, **kwargs)]
```

But I'm not happy that the returned `Callable` does not inherit the signature of the argument types of the input `Callable`. Is there any way to make that happen without making assumptions on the number of arguments of `func`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) adds `ParamSpec` to python-3.10, which allows for:

```
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar
P = ParamSpec('P')
T = TypeVar('T')

def listify(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, List[T]]:
    return lambda *kargs, **kwargs: [func(*kargs, **kwargs)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the release of Python 3.10, and, for older Python versions, the [`typing-extensions` package](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) version 3.10.0 and up, you can use a [`ParamSpec()` construct](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/).

A `ParamSpec()` object acts just like a [`TypeVar()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar), but instead of acting as a placeholder for a single parameter, it models the combination of arguments that a callable accepts.

Use such an object here as the placeholder for the arguments:

```py
from typing import Callable, List, TypeVar
try:
    from typing import ParamSpec
except ImportError:
    from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")

def listify(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, List[T]]:
    return lambda *kargs, **kwargs: [func(*kargs, **kwargs)]
```

If you are stuck with Python 3.4 or older, then you can't do what you want with type hinting, as `type_extensions` 3.10.0 doesn’t support that Python version any more and there is no other syntax to capture the arguments part in a `TypeVar` generic. `Callable` was originally kept simple because it was really only meant to denote callback functions.